# React Unit-Testing - Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Connect(AddUserProfile))"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing

I tried to build a simple component that will popup to allow a user to create a new acocunt like below.

NewAccount.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter,
} from 'reactstrap';
import UserProfile from '../UserProfile/AddNewUserProfile';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const NewAccount = React.memo((props) => {
  const closePopup = (e) => { props.onUserPopupClose(); };
  const history = useHistory()
  const userCreated = () => {
    props.userCreated();
  }

  return (
    <Modal isOpen={props.open} toggle={closePopup} className={"modal-dialog modal-lg"}>
      <ModalHeader toggle={closePopup}>New User</ModalHeader>
      <ModalBody>
        <UserProfile isAddNewUser={true} history={history} userCreated={userCreated} />
      </ModalBody>
      <ModalFooter>
        <Button color="secondary" onClick={closePopup}>Close</Button>
      </ModalFooter>
    </Modal>
  );
});
export default NewAccount;
```

This is my NewAccount.test.js just to test out if it render the modal or not.

```
import React from 'react';
import { screen, render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import NewAccount from '../../components/UserManagement/NewAccount';

jest.mock('../../components/UserProfile', () => {
  const userprofile = () => <div><h4>User Profile</h4></div>;
  return userprofile;
});
describe('new user popup', () => {
  const userCreated = jest.fn();
  const onUserPopupClose = jest.fn();
  beforeEach(() => {
    render(<NewAccount 
      open 
      onUserPopupClose={onUserPopupClose} 
      userCreated={userCreated}/>);
  });
  describe('Structure', () => {
    it('should render the modal', () => {
      expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).toBeInTheDocument();
    });
  });
});
```

This is the error that I got

```
FAIL src/__tests__/UserManagement/NewAccount.test.js
  Stop Error
    ✓ should not error out due to no tests (popper.js.js) (2ms)
  new user popup
    Structure
      ✕ should render the modal (111ms)

  ● new user popup › Structure › should render the modal

    Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Connect(AddUserProfile))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Connect(AddUserProfile)) in connect options.

      12 |   const onUserPopupClose = jest.fn();
      13 |   beforeEach(() => {
    > 14 |     render(<NewAccount 
         |     ^
      15 |       open 
      16 |       onUserPopupClose={onUserPopupClose} 
      17 |       userCreated={userCreated}/>);

      at ConnectFunction (node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:259:15)
      at renderWithHooks (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14803:18)
      at updateFunctionComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17034:20)
      at updateSimpleMemoComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16972:10)
      at updateMemoComponent (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16861:14)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18682:16)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188:14)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
      at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:318:25)
      at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
      at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
      at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
      at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237:16)
      at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292:31)
      at beginWork$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203:7)
      at performUnitOfWork (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22157:12)
      at workLoopSync (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22130:22)
      at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21756:9)
      at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11089:24
      at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
      at runWithPriority$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11084:7)
      at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11072:3)
      at batchedUpdates$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21862:7)
      at act (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
      at render (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:96:26)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/UserManagement/NewAccount.test.js:14:5)

  ● new user popup › Structure › should render the modal

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "dialog"

    There are no accessible roles. But there might be some inaccessible roles. If you wish to access them, then set the `hidden` option to `true`. Learn more about this here: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#byrole

    <body
      class=""
    >
      <div />
    </body>

      19 |   describe('Structure', () => {
      20 |     it('should render the modal', () => {
    > 21 |       expect(screen.getByRole('dialog')).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                     ^
      22 |     });
      23 |   });
      24 | });

      at Object.getElementError (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/config.js:37:19)
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:92:38
      at node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:64:17
      at getByRole (node_modules/@testing-library/dom/dist/query-helpers.js:108:19)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/UserManagement/NewAccount.test.js:21:21)

  console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
    Error: Uncaught [Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Connect(AddUserProfile))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Connect(AddUserProfile)) in connect options.]
        at reportException (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:62:24)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:333:9)
        at invokeEventListeners (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237:16)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292:31)
        at beginWork$1 (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203:7)
        at performUnitOfWork (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22157:12) Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(Connect(AddUserProfile))". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(Connect(AddUserProfile)) in connect options.
        at ConnectFunction (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/connectAdvanced.js:259:15)
        at renderWithHooks (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:14803:18)
        at updateFunctionComponent (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17034:20)
        at updateSimpleMemoComponent (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16972:10)
        at updateMemoComponent (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16861:14)
        at beginWork (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18682:16)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:188:14)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callTheUserObjectsOperation (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventListener.js:26:30)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:318:25)
        at invokeEventListeners (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl._dispatch (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:221:9)
        at HTMLUnknownElementImpl.dispatchEvent (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:94:17)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.dispatchEvent (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/EventTarget.js:231:34)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:237:16)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:292:31)
        at beginWork$1 (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:23203:7)
        at performUnitOfWork (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22157:12)
        at workLoopSync (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22130:22)
        at performSyncWorkOnRoot (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21756:9)
        at /home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11089:24
        at unstable_runWithPriority (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
        at runWithPriority$1 (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
        at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11084:7)
        at flushSyncCallbackQueue (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11072:3)
        at batchedUpdates$1 (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21862:7)
        at act (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-test-utils.development.js:929:14)
        at render (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/pure.js:96:26)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/src/__tests__/UserManagement/NewAccount.test.js:14:5)
        at Object.asyncJestLifecycle (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:53:37)
        at /home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at /home/user1/WebApplication/webapp1/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41

  console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19527
    The above error occurred in the <ConnectFunction> component:
        in ConnectFunction (at NewAccount.jsx:26)
        in div (created by ModalBody)
        in ModalBody (at NewAccount.jsx:25)
        in div (created by Modal)
        in div (created by Modal)
        in div (created by Transition)
        in Transition (created by Fade)
        in Fade (created by Modal)
        in div (created by Modal)
        in Portal (created by Modal)
        in Modal (at NewAccount.jsx:23)
        in Unknown (at NewAccount.test.js:14)
    
    Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.


Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.745s, estimated 4s
```

I'm new to unit-testing .... so I don't know what I did wrong here :(. I have tried to google for few hours and I still can't figure out what wrong with this.

Also if you guys have some video/articles/documentation about how to do unit-testing for React.js noob like me, feel free to share them with me :(

Comment: Is this component `UserProfile ` wrapped with the connect method? If so, you should create a store, and wrapped your component into <Provider>

Comment: UserProfile is working normally. I just have no idea how to write the unit-testing for this...

Comment: Can you tell me how do I create a store, and wrapped the component into <Provider>?

Comment: Just like you do in `store.js`. Move your initStore into test file.